# What is the probability that there is an unusual number of speeches on any given day?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, estimation

Each time parliament convenes there is enough time for 12 speakers on each day on average.

Legislation period lasts for 5 years

Each year there are 4 seassion of 3 calender months and in each session there are exactly 60 days in which parliament convenes.

**Question**

What is the probability that there is an unusual number of speeches on any given day? What is the probability that there is an unusual number of unusual days in a given session?

**My Attempt**

i believe this is the poisson distribution and i thing Lambda = 300 however i am not sure what to do

please help me

Thank you

Comment: What does "unusual" mean?  If it means outside a $95\%$ "most common" interval, then my guess would be the probability might be (almost) $5\%$

Comment: it is considered unusual if the number of speeches is not within 2 standard deviations of the expectation, i also think the mean and lambda are 12?